# MVVM Light and combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox, mvvm-light

I am new to WPF and MVVM Light, I would appreciate if you could help me :-)

I would like to know how to implement a combobox with MVVM Light to do the following:

1) Select an item in the combobox

2) Based on the value selected, change other text fields in the GUI.

Thank you for your help.

Romain

Comment: Post a code with your view model class so that we know which properties should be bound and which properties should be changed.

Answer (score 6):

Well:

View:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceData}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSourceData,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedDataInTextFormat}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Foo> SourceData{get;set;}
    public Foo SelectedSourceData 
    { 
        get{return _selectedFoo;}
        set{_selectedFoo=value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedSourceData");
            SelectedDataInTextFormat=Foo.ToString();
    }

    public string SelectedDataInTextFormat
    {
        get{return _selectedDataInTextFormat;}
        set{_selectedDataInTextFormat=value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDataInTextFormat");
    }
}
```

Basically, to ensure that your view model is able to receive the updated selected item from the combobox make sure the SelectedItem binding is set to Mode=TwoWay.  To ensure that you're pushing data from the viewmodel to the view when a change occuers in the viewmodel make sure you call the RaisePropertyChanged helper class for the property you want updated in the view.